# Promise function do I need use return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to learn pomise and I used code which I found in Internet... I don't understand everything. It looks for me very nasty but it works...

I initialized promise

```
function initialize(city) {
    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0//forecast/',    
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'request'
        }
    };

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request.get(options, function(err, resp, body) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(JSON.parse(body));
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I don't understand why I need to put return after initializePromise.  Is it possible to refactor the code without return?

```
  var initializePromise = initialize("Berlin");
  return initializePromise.then(function(result) {
      weather = result;

      var rain = result["data"][0]["precip"];
      console.log(rain);

  }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  })
```

Comment: depends.... is it in a function that needs to return something?

Comment: I need to get data from request function which is calling API

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it change anything?

Comment: What is the context for the second block of code you give?  Is it inside a function which itself needs to return a promise?  If you, then, yes, you would need return.

Comment: I notice that `initialize` does not use its `city` parameter.  Is it supposed to become part of the url?

Comment: one thing you need to leverage is `.catch()`. The way you are logging out the error is incorrect (looks like callback syntax). so, you should have something that looks like `initializePromise.then(data=>{...}).catch(err =>{...})`

Comment: @LostJon: This is part of the [Promise syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Syntax).  While there are some advantages to the `.catch()` syntax, nothing is wrong with  passing the `onRejected` handler into `then`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet good call...been a WHILE since i used that optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends upon what you want to do.  If you wrote this version, which is slightly altered from your original but functionally the same:

```
function f1(city) {
  return initialize(city).then(function(result) {
    const weather = result
    const rain = result["data"][0]["precip"];
    console.log(rain)
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

then when you call

```
f1('Berlin')
```

you would request the `Berlin` result from the server,  When the server responds, you would either pass to `console.log` the error received from the request or turn the returned body into a JS object, extract the appropriate `precip` property from it, and log that to the console.  The resulting `Promise` value returned from `f1` is useless, and the `weather` variable is unused and unusable.

If you want to log that precipitation, but still keep a useful return value, you can write:

```
function f2(city) {
  return initialize(city).then(function(result) {
    const weather = result
    const rain = result["data"][0]["precip"];
    console.log(rain)
    return weather  // *** NOTE new line here ***
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

This time calling with `Berlin` (and ignoring the error case from now on), you would log the precipitation returned, but also return a Promise for the whole Berlin weather node.  That means you can still do this:

```
f2('Berlin')
```

to log Berlin's first precipitation value, but that now returns a useful value, so you could do

```
f2('Berlin').then(console.log)
```

to do that same logging, and then log the entire Berlin result.

Or you could do

```
f2('Berlin').then(function(weather) {
  // do something useful with `weather` here.
}, errorHandler)
```

But now note the cleanup that is available.  First of all the `rain` variable in `f2` is only used on the next line, and the `weather` one is simply a reference to the original `result` argument.  So we can simplify it this way:

```
function f3(city) {
  return initialize(city).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result["data"][0]["precip"])
    return result
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

This does the same thing more simply.  But now there is a much more important simplification.  It's quite possible that we don't need this function at all!  If we have an error handler of some sort (even if it's just `console.err`), and we already have a function that does most of the weather handling we want, then instead of

```
f3('Berlin').then(function(weather) {
  // do something useful with `weather` here.
}, errorHandler)
```

we can add the logging line from `f3` into this first callbak, and get the same result by calling directly to `initialize`:

```
initialize('Berlin').then(function(weather) {
  console.log(weather["data"][0]["precip"])
  // do something useful with `weather` here.
}, errorHandler)
```

The reason this works is because `initialize` **return**s the result of calling `then` on the Promise, and then `f2` and `f3` also return either an altered value or the original one, keeping a Promise chain intact.

I would suggest that if you're in doubt you return something in any of these situations.  It makes it much easier to continue working with values.